# problems in image cropping functions

Tags: php

For the past few hours I have been trying to crop all the images in a folder using php, but after a series of trials and failures I still cannot run the code successfully; hence, I am calling your help PHP gurus. Thank you

```
<?PHP

require ('plugin15.php');

         $Dir = "/Users/Anay/Desktop/images2";
         $DirEntries = scandir($Dir, 1);
         foreach ($DirEntries as $Entry) {
         echo $Entry;
          }

          $image = imagecreatefrompng("$Entry");
          $copy = PIPHP_ImageCrop($image, 0, 0, 656, 1240);
          if (!$copy) echo "Crop failed: Argument(s) out of bounds";
          else imagepng($copy, "photo1.png");

?>
```

## plugin15.php

```
<?php   


        function PIPHP_ImageCrop($image, $x, $y, $w, $h)
    {
          $tw = imagesx($image);
          $th = imagesy($image);
          if ($x > $tw || $y > $th || $w > $tw || $h > $th)
                      return FALSE;
          $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
          imagecopyresampled($temp, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, 
                      $w, $h, $w, $h);
           return $temp;
    }




?>
```

edit: errors received

failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...

imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...

Crop failed: Argument(s) out of bounds

Comment: "Does not work" is not a sufficient description. You have to write in detail what _should_ happen, what _does_ actually happen, what other things you see, what is shown in the log files and and and. We cannot _guess_ these details...

Comment: You are not checking if `$Entry` is valid, readable PNG file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're passing your $Entry variable to your function incorrectly.  Remove the `""` around $Entry, like so:

`$image = imagecreatefrompng($Entry);`